# SSMS 2012 - Data Only Script Generation With If Not Exists

Tags: scripting, ssms-2012, idempotent, data-generation

I would like to generate a data only insert script within SSMS 2012 which contain the if not exists statements to make the scripts idempotent.

Right clicking the database I wish to generate the script for and selecting Tasks -> Generate Scripts the advanced scripting options within this wizard have been set as follows:

[image: Setup of advanced options]

When this wizard generates the SQL there are no IF NOT EXISTS checks:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([Column1], [Column2]) VALUES (N'Data1', N'Data2')
```

Am I missing something in the scripting options or is this not possible?

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @nozzleman I posted an answer to this problem.

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper I do not see your answer. Can you please share once again?